# Why does Doctrine Query throw "Too many parameters" QueryException

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

This is in controller

```
$candidats = $repository->findList(
$data["recherche_candidat"]["diplomes"],
$data["recherche_candidat"]["categories"]);
```

And this in the repository

```
public function findList($diplomes,$categories,)
{
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    if($categories!=null){
        $qb->andWhere('c.categorie IN (:value)')
            ->setParameter(':value', $categories);
    }

    if($diplomes!=null) {
        $qb->andWhere('c.diplome IN (:value)')
            ->setParameter(':value', $diplomes);
    }

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

problem is when diplomes and categories not null I see an error :

> **Too many parameters: the query defines 1 parameters and you bound 2**
>
> With one null its work; for example diplomes==null and
> categories!=null it work without error

Comment: Giving every parameter the same name probably isn't the best idea.  This is mostly a guess, but try changing the parameter names.

Comment: you mean about (:value) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are giving the same name for both your parameters therefore Doctrine can't make the difference and only recognize 1 parameter. Do something like this:

```
public function findList($diplomes,$categories,) {
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    if($categories!=null){
        $qb->andWhere('c.categorie IN (:categories)')
            ->setParameter(':categories', $categories);
    }

    if($diplomes!=null) {
        $qb->andWhere('c.diplome IN (:diplomes)')
            ->setParameter(':diplomes', $diplomes);
    }

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(); 
}
```

Comment: I think you should not include ':' in the name when setting the parameter. Instead of

setParameter(':value', $categories), try setParameter('value', $categories);